# Did Professors at Hogwarts Take a Salary?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Would the professors of Hogwarts be paid a salary for their teaching?

There's obviously Gringot's where the wizarding world (at least in the UK) would store their riches. I seem to recall there being mention of folks at the Ministry of Magic being paid (I think Ron's dad mentions something about his salary at one point in the movies).

But there's no real mention, as far as I know, of Hogwart's professors being paid, I would assume they'd just live at the school and have their needs met through the 'government'.

It also begs the question of would they be paid in the currency of the local 'muggle world'? Harry visits his parent's vault shortly before heading to Hogwarts and takes out a bunch of galleons to pay his tuition. In the muggle world, this seems like it would be a strange interaction when buying something, ex. paying for groceries using some galleons.

Comment: There is a direct mention, actually, by Slughorn. When he's talking about Acromantula venom (or is it those plants he's surreptitiously cutting from Madam Sprout’s greenhouse?), he says something like, “Quite frankly, the pay isn't impressive”. No specific quotes on how much they earn, though; there's a question about that somewhere, which I do believe this may be a duplicate of.

Answer (score 8):

Slughorn states (in HBP) that Hogwarts Professors do indeed receive a salary. Evidently it's quite puny, in keeping with the general trope that UK teacher are underpaid:

> *Slughorn seemed to be talking more to himself than Harry now.
>
>   ‘… seems an awful waste not to collect it … might get a hundred Galleons a pint … to be frank, **my salary is not large** …’
>
>   And now Harry saw clearly what was to be done.*

Comment: Also from HBP: "All right, I'll do it! But I want Professor Merrythought's office, not that water closet I had before. And I want a raise, these are mad times we live in. MAD! "

Comment: @JoeJMCIT - I'd spend the time adding in some more examples if this question wasn't a dupe. As it stands, it'll get closed in about five mins time and any effort expended will be largely wasted :-)